# AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found. React-native project

Tags: android, flutter, react-native, ionic-framework

when I try to build the APK in my react-native project I'm facing AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

node version : 12.22.12
react-native : 0.63.2
buildToolsVersion : 29.0.2
minSdkVersion : 21
compileSdkVersion : 29
targetSdkVersion : 30
kotlinVersion: 1.3.72

Comment: The error message is self explanatory

Comment: @imamangoo Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating from `react-native@0.64.0` to `react-native@0.64.4` worked for me with this same issue.

As described here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. Add the below mentioned code in the `build.gradle` file under `android/app`

```
    dependencies {
        // implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.64.2") {
            force = true;
        }
   
    }
    

    apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
    

configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.core:core:1.6.0'
            force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
        }
    }
```